# Chain Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a problem with observable chaining.

My goal is to have this result :
`{Pagination, Process[]} and  Process = { ....., Variables[]}`

I'm calling a service which return an object `{Pagination, Process[]}` but Variables in `Process` are empty.

So i need to complete the process object with Variables properties.

I do :

---

```
this.processesService.getData().subscribe(() => {   // data  });
getData: Observable<any> {
   let processesResult = fromPromise( .... );

    return processesResult.pipe(

      map( (result) => { <= result is list of process without variables
        let entries = new Array();

        result.entries.map( **process** =>  {
          result.entries = entries;
          this.getCompleteProcess(**process.id**).subscribe((_process) => {
            entries.push(_process) <-- the process with Variables[] for enrich result map
          })
          return result.entries;
        })
      })
    );
}
```

Can you help me to resolve my problem ? i need to wait `this.getCompleteProcess` to populate parent object and return a complete result

thanks

Comment: Your problem is the classical `wait for an async to complete` problem. You can give a glance to the  [`zip` operator](https://rxmarbles.com/#zip):

Comment: In your case, the numbers (1, 2, 3) are pagination and the letters (A, B, C) are arrays. So after zipping, you'll have couples paginations/arrays

Comment: Thanks,but getCompleteProcess need the process id to enrich Variables of first result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a few operators in rxjs that you could try out (e.g. forkJoin, concatMap). Otherwise what you could also do is to use the Observable.create. For example,

```
getData: Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create( (obs) => {
      let processesResult = fromPromise( .... ).subscribe(
      (result) => { <= result is list of process
        let entries = new Array();
        let obsArr = [];
        result.entries.forEach( **process** =>  {
          result.entries = entries;
          obsArr.push(this.getCompleteProcess(**process.id**).pipe(map((_process) => {
            entries.push(_process) <-- the process is complete and i need it to enrich result map
          });
          forkJoin(...obsArr).subscribe( ([]) => {
               obs.next(result.entries) => EMIT RESPONSE HERE
          } );
        })
      })
    );
}
```

Please note - I have not compiled or tested this. But basically, the idea is to create a wrapping observable which emits a value once all the logic is done. Hope this helps.